# Appendix page and thispagestyle{empty}

Tags: header-footer, appendices

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 12pt, notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,lastpage}% 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
    \fancyhead[L]{\textit{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage\  / \pageref{LastPage}}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\chapter{example}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{appendices}
    %\thispagestyle{empty}
    example
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to remove the header from the title page of the appendices?

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

removes the header only from the page before or after the title page.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plain` page style is used in `appendices` still, but it still has of course the heading settings.

One way is to redefine in the `plain` pagestyle again in the `appendices` environment, with, say `\AtBeginEnvironment`.

`fancyhdr` complains about `headheight` being too small, that's why I adjusted it.

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 12pt, notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}



\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
  \clearpage%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  }
  \thispagestyle{plain}
}

\usepackage[headheight=20pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,lastpage}% 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[L]{\textit{\leftmark}}
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage\  / \pageref{LastPage}}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\chapter{example}
\blindtext[10]
\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{foo}
\blindtext[10]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I remember somehow that's a setting for this in `appendix` package. I'll try to come back

Comment: This would be a good solution, but it removes the fancyhdr at the beginning of the chapter before too.

Comment: @bdvd: Indeed. Which is strange, in my point of view

Comment: @bdvd: A `\clearpage` would be better. I am still wondering about this

Comment: You are right. We should do it with \clearpage